# How do I assign my dynamically created radio buttons in one group?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a code that generates an array of radio buttons and I want to know how to assign them in one group so the other radio buttons won't be enabled if another is enabled.

[image: Multiple radio buttons enabled]

This here is my code for the generation of the said radio buttons.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    RadioButton myRadio = new RadioButton(this);//use array
    myRadio.setId(i);
    final int id_ = myRadio.getId();
    myRadio.setText("button " + id_);
    LinearLayout li = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    li.addView(myRadio, lp);
    btn = (RadioButton) findViewById(id_);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Button clicked index = " + id_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

btn is a button declared outside the function. It is also a radio button

Comment: Add them all to a [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code sample

```
final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[20];
    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); //create the RadioGroup
    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
       rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
       rg.addView(rb[i]);           
       rb[i].setText(" " + ContactsActivity.phonetype.get(i)
            + "    " + ContactsActivity.phone.get(i));
       rb[i].setId(i + 100);

    }
    ll.addView(rg);//you add the whole RadioGroup to the layout
```

**Update - Answer for the error you mentioned in your comments**

To resolve your error, find out, using the line-number in the error, which line produces the error. Look at what you are adding there

Check all your addView calls. (hint: there is a line-number in that error somewhere. use it)

To try to answer your question in the comment, you must follow these rules;

1. Never add any view more then once.
2. When a View is already used (e.g., you got it with findViewById, don't use addView on it.
   When you want to add a view, use addView with a NEW view.
3. You can add several of these new views to one view, but you cannot add that one view multiple times.

Comment: I've received this error after trying the code "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeview() on the child's parent first"

Comment: @MarkCortejo, Try removing the line rg.addView(radiobutton[i]); .. Check my updated answer for more information